# Azure Front Door - Convert all incoming url's to lowercase

Tags: azure-static-web-app, azure-front-door, azure-static-website-routing

I've configured Azure Front Door to route traffic to a Static Web App. I want to create rule/s such that any incoming URL to the Front Door gets transformed to lowercase.

E.g. https://endp-c3sdsfsddd.z03.azurefd.net/Images/Admin/Test.png becomes https://endp-c3sdsfsddd.z03.azurefd.net/images/admin/test.png

I was following this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/99081/front-door-rule-engine-transform-to-lowercase-(bug but this is a very specific case. Wondering whether all incoming URLs can be lowercase.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Front Door - Convert all incoming URL's to lowercase: -

For converting all incoming `URL's` to lowercase, you need to add a rule under `rule engine configuration` in a `front door` profile.

To create it, you need to use a combination of `Request Header Modification` and `URL Rewrite` actions as shown below.

*Path*: `Front Door and CDN profiles >> Settings >> Rules engine configuration`

*Add a rule:*

[image]

*Add a request header and select transform action as* `To Lowercase`:

[image]

Once you configure actions according to your requirement, save it and you are done with the rule configuration that transforms all redirect URL's to lowercase.

Reference: [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-tutorial-rules-engine#configure-rules-engine-in-azure-portal)